# Can an attacker change an old block without changing the checksum?

Tags: security

Since multiple values can result in the same hash, couldn’t an attacker try to find a way of increasing his balance in a way that the checksum of the changed block remains the same (so that any proofs-of-work are still valid) and then propagate the change into the network without peers noticing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, he can try. But the algorithms Bitcoin uses were specifically chosen to make this attack completely impractical. It would be trillions of times easier to just buy the Bitcoins.

Comment: And suppose he could come up with such a block (he can't, but for arguments sake). How is he going to give that block to others? Noone is going to replace a block that's been on their harddisks for years with a new one. He could only pollute the  blockchain of some random new user downloading a fresh copy. Surely an awkward situation for a few individuals, but hardly a significant fork.